# Is there a MAX size for a table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 150Million records with 300 columns (nchar),I am running a script to import data to the database database but it is always stopping when it gets to 10Million..

Is there a MSSQL setting that controls how many records can be on a table? What can it be making it stop at 10Million?

Edit:
I have run the script multiple times and it has been able to create multiple tables, but they all max at the same 10million records

Comment: 300 columns? Are you sure, you don't want to little split up you table?

Comment: I will be cleaning the data once its all in..

Comment: Is there a max size?  Not really - but you are bound by how much physical space you have on disc.  But if it gets too large, you may want to consider partitioning.

Comment: Just from the feeling the table needs at least 500GB of place.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the definition of the table in the database?  If you are using `char()` or `nchar()`, for instance, the resulting table might be bigger than you expect.  Also, how large is the source data file?

Comment: I don't think space is the issue, since I can rerun the script and it creates a new table with the same 10 Million more records

Comment: There is no such limit on tables in SQL Server.  This is very likely a problem with your script.

Comment: What exactly happens after 10 million rows?

Comment: My application is giving me an error "Error Insertnig, Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to comletion of the operation or the server is not responding"

Answer (score -1):

depends on available storage. The more available storage you have, the more rows can you have in a table